# The mechanics in sequence of Python Function Arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, arguments

The following is an excerpt from a simple python example from the book "Python Crash course" 
My question relates to the arguments fire_bullet takes. I want to know why "line 4: len(bullets)" despite having 'bullets' clearly specified in its brackets, insists on taking the last arguments in "line 1:  def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets)", so if I don't place bullets as the last argument here, then the codes will NOT work.  For instance, if I swap the place of "bullets" with "ship" then "line 4:if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:" will attempt to regard 'bullet's as an object of 'ship' and produce 'TypeError: object of type 'Ship' has no len()'

I know the general rule that positional arguments by the very definition require a specific order, but in the following example the arguments are unmistakably spelled out as if they were named arguments and further, if indeed 'line 1:def fire_bullet' needed its arguments in specific position then, why is the first 'line 4 : len(bullets) insisting on reading the last argument 'in line 1: bullets'

```
1. def fire_bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship, bullets):
2.    """Fire a bullet if limit no reached yet."""
3.   (# omitted) Create a new bullet and add it to the bullets group
4.    if len(bullets) < ai_settings.bullets_allowed:
5.            new_bullet = Bullet(ai_settings, screen, ship)
6.            bullets.add(new_bullet)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with the naming of the arguments, and everything to do with how the function `fire_bullet` is called in practice.  The code snippet you posted will run just fine on its own if you switch up the arguments, but somewhere else in the program the function `fire_bullet` is being called with a list as the final argument.  If you wanted to change the  order that the arguments appear in, you should also make sure that every call of the `fire_bullet` function has the arguments in the new order.

Answer (score 0):

In other words, here is what is wrong (with classic example foobar()):

```
def foobar(a, b):
    print(b)

foobar(1, 2) # this will print 2
foobar(2, 1) # this will print 1
# As you can see, order matters not
# only when you write the function, 
# but when you call it as well
```

In your program somewhere else, you have the order mixed up when you call the function fire_bullet.